# storing sql column value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are doing some database refactoring and are moving some data from one table to another. Previously we had an "offerrequest"-table that had address information(city ,streetaddress,postalcode etc.) stored directly in it. Now we are moving address data to separate "address"-table that contains the specific address fields an are referencing that table in the "offerrequest"-table. The problem is that some legacy applications still use the fields in the 
offerrequest-table to access data. Is there any way to make insert/update queries made against the offerrequest-table to save address data to the address table when the legacy addressfields are used in the query. SQL-server we use mssql-server 2008

Comment: My first thought is related to a trigger. (Or find the sp that is performing insert/update and modify it )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a trigger like described by @FabianBigler, here is the syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT Employee_Test_Audit
       (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,'Created by insert trigger',getdate()
FROM INSERTED

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

you could replace the offerrequest-table with a view. something like that:

```
   create view offerrequest 
    as 
    select new_offerrequest.data, adress.data 
    from 
             new_offerrequest 
    join 
             adress 
          on 
             new_offerrequest.adress_id=adress.id
```

Comment: Yes, go with the view. Then create a trigger on the view so that the legacy code operates on the view just as it did the original table. The code doesn't even have to know there was any change made to the tables. That is what views are for.

Answer (score 0):

do something like

```
create trigger replacetrg on offerrequest
**instead of** insert,update,delete
as ...---instead of insert/update/delete on offerrequest
       --do it on address.
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an after insert [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to achieve that.
This would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
    select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
    select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

SQL example extracted from [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server).

**EDIT:** Please use t-clausen.dk's answer since it also supports multiple rows.

Comment: this trigger will only trigger once for  each insert. Even with 10 rows inserted

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I'm not sure about that. However, if there are multiple rows inserted at once, you could also get the delta from table1 and table2 and insert the missing rows.
I'm just trying to give an idea about how to approach this.

Comment: What happens when an insert query is made without Emp_Sal defined?

Comment: @Jargo It probably throws an error, because it will try to insert a NULL into the other table. In your scenario, you will only have the related address columns in your trigger.

Comment: @Fabian Bigler The problem with that approach is that the insert/update query may not contain all the address fields.

Comment: @DudiKonfino I provided a link which also includes Update, Delete etc. I guess it's enough to show INSERT Trigger to give an idea of how to solve it.

Comment: your link is equally bad. Inserted and deleted are local tables. You are treating it as it was one row only. I even showed you the correct syntax.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk your solution seems to be neater because it also supports multiple rows and uses less SQL to achieve it.